# Question regarding mani ( semen )

Tags: salat

My question might sound stupid but I attained puberty very recently and I don't know the answers to these questions. I tried many other sources but with no success.

1. If you *woke up with a erection*  does that indicate that you had a nocturnal ejaculation  ?
2. If you *had a ejaculation yesterday is it possible to have a nocturnal ejaculation today* also ? Like wouldn't all the mani go out with the first ejaculation ?

The above two questions' italicised parts indicate my situation. Yesterday I had an ejaculation so isy it possible to have a nocturnal ejaculation today also ? What's more today when I woke up I had an erection.

When I checked my underwear I couldn't find any liquid stains but I was wearing a chequered multicolour underwear which makes it difficult to identify any stains in the first place - I checked very well but I couldnt see any stains.  What's more there is a hole in my underwear and when I woke up my penis was poking out of this hole and touching my trouser. On my trouser there was some small patches about 0.5 cm in diameter. However you could only notice them if you looked very carefully. I smelt it but I couldn't Identify a big difference in smell from the area with the patches and the area without the patches on my trouser. They say dried semen smells like rotten eggs but I don't know what rotten eggs smell like and I haven't smelt semen before. The patches had a slight smell but not a strong one. I could be psychologically fooled ( I have waswas problem too ).
The patches could be very well water or wadhi but I am not sure.

In this situation I am unable to decide whether I have had a nocturnal ejaculation or not. I don't remember having a sexual dream but you have to do ghusl anyway if mani came out . I am unable to decide whether I have released mani or not. In this case it would be useful if you could answer questions 1 and 2 above so that I can arrive at a conclusion.

Edit : I did a small test that I do after ejaculation. Which is to take a tissue and wipe the tip of the penis. If the tip feels sticky that means semen must have come out. If not no semen must have come out . I did the test and the tip didn't feel sticky .But this method is not foolproof as it cannot indicate the presence of dry semen. However I checked the tip of my pen is an coudnt see any dried substance there. But I am still not sure whether I ejaculated or not. Is this test suffice to proof that I have not ejaculated against the patches that are on my trouser ?

Please answer me before the time for Zuhr prayer ends so I can either take ghusl and pray or just pray

Comment: If you are unable to decide whether it is Mani or Madhiy, then simply assume that it is Mani and do ghusl. That way your prayer will be valid regardless of what it actually was. The characteristics of both are already explained (e.g. [here](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/2458)), beyond that any person whose sole source of information is your description is not in any better a position than yourself in judging what it is.

Answer (score 0):

1. Not really, it's actually quite normal for men (grown ups). It's called Morning Wood.
2. Yes, it's possible.

Mani smells like chlorine (like what they use in swimpool) from my experience. If you can't find any difference between smell, then it could be Madhi (also known as prec*m). You don't need to do Ghusl for Madhi. (Btw in your case it could also be Wadhi idk)

"I felt greatly distressed by the frequent flowing of prostatic fluid. For this reason I used to take a bath very often. I asked the apostle of Allah (ﷺ) about this. He replied: Ablution will be sufficient for you because of this. I asked: Messenger of Allah, what should I do if it smears my clothes. He replied: It is sufficient if you take a handful of water and sprinkle it on your clothe when you find it has smeared it."

[Abi Dawud 210](https://sunnah.com/abudawud:210)
Grade: Hasan (al Albani)

"I was one who had a lot of prostatic discharge, and the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said to me: 'If you see Madhi (prostatic fluid) then wash your penis and perform Wudu' like that for Salah, but if you ejaculate semen, then perform Ghusl.'"

[Sunan an-Nasa'i](https://sunnah.com/urn/1101940)

Wallahu a'lam